# Truth table with Boolean Functions

Tags: python, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, truthtable

I am trying to generate a Truth Table using PANDAS in python.
I have been given a Boolean Network with 3 external nodes (U1,U2,U3) and 6 internal nodes (v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6).
I have created a table with all the possible combinations of the 3 external nodes which are 2^3 = 8.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

in_comb = list(itertools.product([0,1], repeat = 3))
df = pd.DataFrame(in_comb)
df.columns = ['U1','U2','U3']
df.index += 1
```

| U1 | U2 | U3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

And I also have created the same table but with all the possible combinations of the 6 internal nodes which are 2^6 = 64 combinations.

The functions for each node were also given

```
v1(t+1) = U1(t)
v2(t+1) = v1(t) and U2(t)
v3(t+1) = v2(t) and v5(t)
v5(t+1) = not U3(t)
v6(t+1) = v5(t) or v3(t)
```

The truth table has to be done with PANDAS and it has to show all the combinations with each combination possible.

For example.

| v1 | v2 | v3 | v4 | v5 | v6 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 1 | 0 1 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 000010 | 000000 | 000010 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  |  |  |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |  |  |  |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |

The table above is an example of how the end product should be. Where the [0 0 0] is the first combination of the external nodes.

I am confused as to how to compute the functions of each gene and how to filter the data and end up with a new table like the one here.

Here I attach an image of the problem I want to solve:

[image: Image of problem]

Comment: I think you would want to create a [state transition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_table). There are multiple forms for it. Is there any specification on what form should you use?

Comment: Hello, yes, the task given is to make a state transition table, and no, there is no specification.

Comment: Hello again and sorry for the late reply but yes, that was the output i was expecting. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You can upvote & accept my answer to mark it helpful. This awards the answerer some rep points too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to have missed is the fact that you don't only have 3 inputs to your network, as the "old state" is also considered an input - that's what a feedback combinational network does, it turns the old state + input into new state (and often output).

This means that you have 3+6 inputs, for 2^9=512 combinations. Not very easy to understand when printed, but still possible. I modified your code to print this (beware that I'm quite new to pandas, so this code can definitely be improved)

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
import itertools

#list of (u, v) pairs (3 and 6 elements)
# uses bools instead of ints
inputs = list((row[0:3],row[3:]) for row in itertools.product([False,True], repeat = 9))

def new_state(u, v):
    # implement the itnernal nodes
    return (
        u[0],
        v[0] and u[1],
        v[1] and v[4],
        v[2],
        not u[2],
        v[4] or v[2]
    )

new_states = list(new_state(u, v) for u,v in inputs)
# unzip inputs to (u,v), add new_states
raw_rows = zip(*zip(*inputs), new_states)

def format_boolvec(v):
    """Format a tuple of bools like (False, False, True, False) into a string like "0010" """
    return "".join('1' if b else '0' for b in v)

formatted_rows = list(map(lambda row: list(map(format_boolvec, row)), raw_rows))

df = pd.DataFrame(formatted_rows)
df.columns = ['U', "v(t)", "v(t+1)"]
df.index += 1

df
```

The heart of it is the function `new_state` that takes the `(u, v)` pair of input & old state and produces the resulting new state. It's a direct translation of your specification.

I modified your `itertools.product` line to use `bool`s, produce length-9 results and split them to 3+6 length tuples. To still print in your format, I added the `format_boolvec(v)` function. Other than that, it should be very easy to follow, but fell free to comment if you need more explanation.

To find an input sequence from a given start state to a given end state, you could do it yourself by hand, but it's tedious. I recommend using a graph algorithm, which is easy to implement since we also know the length of the desired path, so we don't need any fancy algorithms like Bellman-Ford or Dijkstra's - we need to just generate all length=3 paths and filter for the endpoint.

```py
# to find desired inputs
# treat each state as a node in a graph
# (think of visual graph transition diagrams)
# and add edges between them labeled with the inputs
# find all l=3 paths, and check the end nodes

nodes = {format_boolvec(prod): {} for prod in itertools.product([False,True], repeat = 6)}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    nodes[row['v(t)']][row['U']] = row['v(t+1)']

# we now built the graph, only need to find a path from start state to end state

def prefix_paths(prefix, paths):
    # aux helper function for all_length_n_paths
    for path, endp in paths:
        yield ([prefix]+path, endp)

def all_length_n_paths(graph, start_node, n):
    """Return all length n paths from a given starting point
    Yield tuples (path, endpoint) where path is a list of strings of the inputs, and endpoint is the end of the path.
    Uses internal recursion to generate paths"""
    if n == 0:
        yield ([], start_node)
        return
    for inp, nextstate in graph[start_node].items():
        yield from prefix_paths(inp, all_length_n_paths(graph, nextstate, n-1))


# just iterate over all length=3 paths starting at 101100 and print it if it end's up at 011001
for path, end in all_length_n_paths(nodes, "101100", 3):
    if end=="011001":
        print(path)
```

This code should also be easy to follow, maybe except that iterator syntax.

The result is not just one, but 3 different paths:

> ['100', '110', '011']
> ['101', '110', '011']
> ['111', '110', '011']